# Best approach to monitor download progress with OneDrive API on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I have a WP8.1 app using the new `OneDrive API`. I use the C# SDK provided, I get therefore something like this:

```
var dlStream = await Connection.DownloadStreamForItemAsync(mNode.ItemReference(),
                                                   StreamDownloadOptions.Default);
file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, 
                                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).AsTask();

fileStream = (await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)).AsStream();

var v=dlStream.CopyToAsync(tn.FileStream);
```

I have not tried it yet, but it seems to be the right way to do it. My concern now is "how to monitor the transfer progress and status?"

Knowing that the DownloadStreamForItemAsync method does something like this:

```
response = await GetHttpResponseAsync(request);
var responseStream = await response.GetResponseStreamAsync();
```

I have thought about using a timer, and each second check the stream length, but

1. I don't know if it is the right approach of if there is an alternative way
2. I don't know if this may not create some cross-thread errors for the stream
3. How to detect a transfer failure ?

I guess one of the approaches would be to re-write partially the OneDrive SDK portable project, target only WinRT projects and use Windows.Web objects instead of System.Net, but it seems to be some work for an unsure result.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LiveConnectClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.aspx) class inside the `Live SDK` instead of downloading the file as a stream and saving it to a file.

1. Use the [`BackgroundDownloadAsync(string path, Uri downloadLocation)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219338.aspx) method to download a file

   > Begins downloading a file from Microsoft OneDrive to a Windows Phone
   >   isolated storage. [Windows Phone only]
   >   The file download should continue even if the app that starts the file
   >   download quits or is suspended.
2. Subscribe to the [`BackgroundDownloadProgressChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.backgrounddownloadprogresschanged.aspx) event

   > Raised at indeterminate times while a file is downloading from Microsoft OneDrive to Windows Phone isolated storage. [Windows Phone only]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I am still on this issue. I have decided not to use the LiveSDK and stick to the new OneDrive API. It is probably much more complicated, but the LiveSDK does not fit my needs.